# How do I construct a function given two data points on a Cartesian grid and the constraint that it is inversely proportional to a power of $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given:

$[ 1 , \sqrt{2} ]$

$[ 8 , 0.5 ]$

And the constraint that:
$f(x)$ is inversely proportional to the power of $x$, such that: $y = 1 / x^n$.

How do I construct the function that relates $y$ and $x$?

I know that the answer is:
$$y = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{x^{1/2}}$$

But I found this result empirically by tweaking functions using the Desmos graphing calculator.

How would you derive the function $f(x)$ mathematically given only the two data points and the constraint outlined above?

My result is in the image below:

https://res.cloudinary.com/dtmuylvrr/image/upload/v1583936659/Screenshot_2020-03-11_at_10.19.15.png

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this website.

Comment: thank you @N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $y=\frac {k}{x^n}$

You know that $y=\sqrt 2$ when $x=1$. This means that $\sqrt 2=\frac{k}{1^n} \Rightarrow \sqrt2=k$

You also know that $y=\frac 12$ when $x=8$. his means that $\frac 12=\frac{\sqrt 2}{8^n} \Rightarrow 8^n=2\sqrt2$

Note that $2\sqrt2=\sqrt 4 \times \sqrt2=\sqrt 8$ and $\sqrt 8 =8^{\frac 12}$

So $8^n=2\sqrt2$ becomes $8^n=8^{\frac 12} \Rightarrow n=\frac 12$

Comment: Thank you @tomi for taking the time to answer my question!

Just one more thing: It's this derivation that I struggle to understand:
$ 8^n=2\sqrt2=\sqrt 8=8^{\frac 12} $

Comment: I've tried to explain more fully in the answer.

Comment: Thank you @tomi

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You know , about the ordered pair, i.e.,  the point $(1, f(1))$ that

$(1, f(1))$ = (1,$\frac{k}{1^n})$ = (1, $\sqrt2$).

Snce 2 points are equal iff both their $x$ coordinates and $y$ cordinates are equal, you can conclude that :

$(1)$ $f(1)$ = $\frac{k}{1^n}$ = $\sqrt2$.

By the same reasoning about the point $(8, f(8))$, you can conclude that

$(2)$ $f(8)$ = $\frac{k}{8^n}$ = $\frac12$.

After that, one needs some algebra to solve for $k$ and for $n$.

Once it has been found , by solving $(1)$ that $k= \sqrt2$, equation (2) in particular can be solved as an exponential equation.

$\frac{\sqrt2}{8^n}$ = $\frac12$.

$\rightarrow$ $8^n\times1$ = $2\times\sqrt2$ ( by cross product)

$\rightarrow$ $8^n$ = $2^1\times2^{\frac 12}$  ( by $\sqrt a = a^{\frac 12}$)

$\rightarrow$ $8^n$ = $2^{\frac 32}$  ( by "product of powers" rule, exponents are added)

$\rightarrow$ $\left(2^3\right)^n$ = $2^{\frac 32}$ ( because $8=2^3$)

$\rightarrow$ $(2)^{3\times n}$ = $2^{\frac 32}$ ( by "power of a power" rule)

$\rightarrow$  $3n$ = $\frac 32$ ( by " equal powers with same base have equal exponents")

$\rightarrow$ $n$ = $\frac{\frac 32} {3}$ = $\frac 12$.